# In Gatsby how do I pass a relative path file to a template that is also pulling a query?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

In Gatsby I've coded a single post template:

*singlePost.js:*

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { MDXRenderer } from 'gatsby-plugin-mdx'
import { H1 } from '../elements'
import { Container, Post, FeatureImage } from '../components'
const singlePost = ({ data }) => {
  const featureImage = data.mdx.frontmatter.featureImg.childImageSharp.fixed
  return (
    <Container>
      <FeatureImage fixed={featureImage} />
      <Post>
        <H1 margin=" 0 0 2rem 0">{data.mdx.frontmatter.title}</H1>
        <MDXRenderer>{data.mdx.body}</MDXRenderer>
      </Post>
    </Container>
  )
}
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query SinglePostQuery($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        date
        excerpt
        featureImg {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 1920) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
        title
        slug
      }
    }
  }
`
export default singlePost
```

In my *gatsby-node.js* I get the data from the slug:

```
 data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => {
    const slug = edge.node.frontmatter.slug
    const id = edge.node.id
    actions.createPage({
      path: slug,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/singlePost.js`),
      context: { id },
    })
  })
```

In the frontmatter of the markdown file there is a feature image:

```
---
title: Bacon Ipsum
slug: bacon
date: 2021-02-09
featureImg: nature.jpg
excerpt: Bacon ipsum dolor amet pastrami prosciutto meatball fatback, andouille drumstick shank burgdoggen brisket cow turkey.
---
```

if the post markdown file doesn't have an image I get an error of:

> Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null

I can access the default image I've set with:

```
const defaultImage = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    default: file(relativePath: { eq: "default.jpg" }) {
      publicURL
    }
  }
`)
```

but when I try to query for the content and the default with:

```
const defaultImage = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query SinglePostQuery($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        date
        excerpt
        featureImg {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 1920) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
        title
        slug
      }
    }
    default: file(relativePath: { eq: "default.jpg" }) {
      publicURL
    }
  }
`)
```

I get an error of:

> If you're not using a page query but a useStaticQuery / StaticQuery
> you see this error because they currently don't support variables.

In Gatsby how can I query the slug but also have pass the default image to the Feature Image component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error log points, `useStaticQuery` (because it's a type of static query) doesn't accept variables, hence the name.

> In Gatsby how can I query the slug but also have pass the default
> image to the Feature Image component?

You can use the same context where you attach the `id` to pass the image while using page queries.

```
  data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => {
        const slug = edge.node.frontmatter.slug
        const id = edge.node.id
        const imagePath = edge.node.featureImg || 'default.jpg'
        actions.createPage({
          path: slug,
          component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/singlePost.js`),
          context: { 
            id 
            imagePath
           },
        })
      })
```

*Note: You may need to query the image in your `gatsby-node.js`. Change the `imagePath` to another identifier that matches better your data structure if needed.*

Then, in your template:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { MDXRenderer } from 'gatsby-plugin-mdx'
import { H1 } from '../elements'
import { Container, Post, FeatureImage } from '../components'
const singlePost = ({ data }) => {
  const featureImage = data.mdx.frontmatter.featureImg.childImageSharp.fixed
  return (
    <Container>
      <FeatureImage fixed={featureImage} />
      <Post>
        <H1 margin=" 0 0 2rem 0">{data.mdx.frontmatter.title}</H1>
        <MDXRenderer>{data.mdx.body}</MDXRenderer>
      </Post>
    </Container>
  )
}
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query SinglePostQuery($id: String!, $imagePath: String) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        date
        excerpt
        featureImg {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 1920) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
        title
        slug
      }
    }
    default: file(relativePath: { eq: $imagePath }) {
      publicURL
    }
  }
`
export default singlePost
```

*Note: add the `$imagePath` as a nullable value (by removing the exclamation mark, `!`), since, as you said, not all the posts will have it.*

Try removing the `featureImg` block if it stills breaking the query. Because of:

```
const imagePath = edge.node.featureImg || 'default.jpg'
```

Your `imagePath` variable will always contain the needed data,or your `featureImg`, or your default one. The key is to make separate queries.